# Do I need to free instance of TJSONArray

Tags: json, delphi

The answer is obviously yes, but I have this code that has been running for almost a month now 24/7 and everything is fine. Here is the code :

```
var
  jsonArray : TJSONArray;
  jsonValue : TJSONValue;
  json : string;
begin

  json := 'JSON_MASTER';
  jsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), 0) as TJSONArray;
  for jsonValue in jsonArray do
  begin
    // do the thing 1
  end;

  json := 'JSON_DETAIL';
  jsonArray := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json), 0) as TJSONArray;
  for jsonValue in jsonArray do
  begin
    // do the thing 2
  end;

end;
```

The application is a web service(SOAP). The function is executed around 2K per day. I am aware of the issue in the code but because the SOAP is not crushing I'm not fixing it yet. The task manager performance report shows fine. There is no sign of growing memory usage. Why is there no sign of memory leaks? Is there such thing as garbage collection in TJSONArray?

Comment: Hello, @Ago! I have to admit I have never worked with JSON, but I think it is a good practice to destroy any object(-s) you have created manually. You also cannot rely on task manager info - it doesn't mirror real information about how your application is working. It is also unable to show you memory leaks in your app. For the last one you must use special libraries allowing to check if there is some hidden memory consumption or non-released memory blocks. For this I would recommend you free `FastMM`. In my opinion, it is a fantastical luck that SOAP is working stable all the time.

Comment: General rules should apply i.e. when you `.Create` an object you must `.Free` it also. Documentation is not good though, it should mention any exceptions like '.ParseJSONValue' where also need to `.Free`.

Answer (score 3):

### It depends on which platform you are running on.

If your app is running on a non-ARC platform, such as Windows or OSX, then YES, you need to manually free the `TJSONArray` when you are done using it, or else it will be leaked.

If your app is running on an ARC platform, such as iOS, Android, or Linux, then NO, you do not need to manually free the `TJSONArray` when you are done using it, as it will be freed automatically when all references to it have gone out of scope.

Comment: good to know now that automatic reference counting can help to clear all the 'garbage'. My programming experience is ends only with Windows OS.

Comment: In other words: TJSONArray is a class so yes, you must manually Free it if it isn't on an ARC platform, like any other class.